# How can I get this complicated query to work with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a complicated SQL query involving 3 models, creating virtual attributes based off of time operations...  Ideally I would want to use ActiveRecord arel methods to generate this so that it's nicer, but I have no idea how.

```
  find_by_sql <<--sql
    SELECT username, count(*) as records, AVG(time_taken) as time_taken
    FROM (
      SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, posts.created_at, reports.created_at) as time_taken,
             users.username as username
      FROM reports, users, posts
      WHERE reports.user_id = users.id AND 
            reports.post_id = posts.id
    ) AS dashboard_data # this name is unused, but apparently required
    GROUP BY username
  sql
```

Is there any way to do something like this within ActiveRecord?  Or is raw sql the only way to do complicated stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's from a table you're going to be stuck doing things like this. You're fetching from a subquery which is way outside the scope of what ActiveRecord is intended to do. An ORM is designed to map objects to specific rows in well-defined tables.

You can sometimes fake it so that whatever you're doing appears to be sufficiently table-like that it works by using a SQL view. ActiveRecord will gladly use a view if it can be queried like a table. For instance if it has an `id` column defined that serves as some sort of primary key it should work. In your case you could `GROUP BY users.id` and have `users.id AS id` exposed as well as `users.username`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is equivalent to what you're doing:

```
User.joins({:reports=>:posts}).
     group("users.username").
     select("users.username, 
             count(*) as records,
             avg(timestampdiff(hour, posts.created_at, reports.created_at)) as time_taken")
```